# Backup data from RDS to S3 and delete from RDS once copied to S3

Tags: amazon-rds, aws

We have a requirement werein we have to backup data from RDS(MYSQL and Postgres) to S3 incrementally and to delete the already copied data from RDS. I thought of using aws data-pipeline for this, however data pipeline is not supported in mumbai region. please suggest any other way to accomplish this task.